# Connecting to vibro meter system via tcp connection with C#

Tags: c#

I want to receive data from Vibro meter machine via tcp connection in Visual C# program.

I am new to C#. Is there anybody who can help me write code of tcp connection and refer me references to study?

My goal is to write a program in C# to read data from VibroMeter machine. Please help. Thanks for reading my request.

Best regards

Comment: Have you attempted anything that you can show in your question? Are you running into any specific issues?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think you're looking for something more like Chegg tutors: https://www.chegg.com/tutors/.

Comment: hi mr kevin lamb